# raster-derived KMZ cannot display in google map api v3

Tags: google-maps-api, kmz, geotiff-tiff

I got some raster(tiff)-generated KMZ files, but they cannot be displayed at all in googe map api v3. However, all of my shapefile-generated KMZ files can be displayed properly. Anyone faced the similar situation before?

Comment: How were these KMZs generated? Which software are you using? Can you provide us an example?